# Removing Line Break Tags from a Page

Tags: html, formatting

I am running the latest version of Wordpress on the Genesis Framework with the AgentPress theme. There is an annoying four line gap between the page title and the Wordpress Post Tab  widget that I have installed. Using Firebug, I discovered that the gap is caused by four line break tags < br > , which seem to be automatically generated since I did not include them in the text editor.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide `<br />` elements with CSS using `display:none;` ofcourse you might want to try going into your post editor and removing any blank lines.

WordPress converts line breaks into 
 tags for you automatically when the content is rendered using a function like `the_content()`.